# Give full permissions to the owner and only one other user

Tags: files, permissions

I have three users in Redhat 6 machine,

```
tiger
gourav
sourav
```

User gourav and sourav in brother group.
Now user tiger create a directory tiger_gaurav and want to give read and write permission to only and only gourav user.

When I try to give permission according to group,sourav also gets the permission to access that directory.
Please do help me with this.

Comment: Can you create a new group that contains only those people you want to share this directory with?

Comment: Are your filesystems ACL-enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ACL's this can be done ([Red Hat - Setting Access ACLs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/acls-setting.html)) -

```
$ setfacl -m u:gourav:rwx,d:u:gourav:rwx,d:u:tiger:rwx,m:rwx path/tiger_gaurav
```

- `u:gourav:rwx` — grants user gourav read,write, and execute to the directory
- `d:u:gourav:rwx` — sets the default rule that will grant user gourav read,write,execute permission to files created in the directory
- `d:u:tiger:rwx` — sets the default rule that will grant user tiger read,write,execute permission to files created in the directory
- `m:rwx` — sets the mask, this value is unioned with the owning group and all other users/groups.

That said, creating a group is likely much simpler to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Create a group that only the two belong to, and use that as group access. Remember, an account can be a member of many groups.